# XCODE 6.4 - Undefined symbols for architecture armv7 error

Tags: ios, objective-c, google-cloud-messaging, armv7

My which was working fine until GCM integration, now give below error.

> Undefined symbols for architecture armv7 error

I am using the Architecture sam as that of sample app provided by google [HERE](https://github.com/googlesamples/google-services/blob/master/ios/gcm/GcmExample/AppDelegate.m)

[image]

But it is giving below error after using GCM code for Appdelegate.m

[image]

If anyone has faced problem ,please help me in resolving this issues..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This solved my issue by add **"$inhertied"** to linker flags in targets

[image]

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like the GCM library only has object code for the simulator and is failing when you try to build it for your iOS device.

That's strange. Usually the problem is the opposite - vendors supply compiled code only for the device and it fails when you build for the simulator.

I haven't used GCM before so I don't have any specific info to give you. Try building for the simulator and for iOS devices, not the different errors, and then read up on how you build GCM for the simulator and for iOS devices.

Comment: Ok, so you should either accept my answer, or post your own answer with the details and accept that (That's the better option so future readers with the same problem can learn from your post.)